# add Count to SQL query in Propel

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I have in my project old version (1.2) Propel. I would like make query:

```
SELECT city_id, COUNT(*) FROM House GROUP BY city_id
```

I tried:

```
  $c = new Criteria;
  $c->addAsColumn('count', 'Count(' . HousePeer::CITY_ID . ')'); 
  $this->results = HousePeer::doSelect($c);
```

but this not working - return me only first record from database, without count etc.

i tried also:

```
$con = Propel::getConnection();
$sql = "SELECT city_id, COUNT(*) FROM House GROUP BY city_id";
$stmt = $con->createStatement();
$rs = $stmt->executeQuery($sql, ResultSet::FETCHMODE_NUM);
$this->results = HousePeer::populateObjects($rs);
```

but this throw me

```
Error populating House object [wrapped: Invalid resultset column: 3]
```

I would like only receive same as in SQL table:

```
city_id | count
1       | 2
2       | 4
3       | 3
```

etc

or get name City from CityPeer (i have correctly relations between City and House)
for example:

```
city       | count
New York   | 2
Paris      | 4
Washington | 3
```

but i can't use this query in Propel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [a great example](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/257) in the old snippet from symfony.

Try:

```
$c = new Criteria;
$c->clearSelectColumns()->addSelectColumn(HousePeer::CITY_ID);
$c->addGroupByColumn(HousePeer::CITY_ID);
$c->addAsColumn('numCity', 'COUNT('.HousePeer::CITY_ID.')');
$c->addJoin(HousePeer::CITY_ID, CityPeer::ID);

$rs = HousePeer::doSelectRS($c);

while ($rs->next())
{
  // etc ...
}
```